# Null ImageView Reference

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I'm trying to get a reference to an ImageView object and for whatever reason, it keeps coming back as null.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="6dip">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/application_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label" android:text="Application Name" />
  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.application_icon);
```

I don't feel like I'm doing anything wrong yet my img var always comes back as null. What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: Does v refer to the LinearLayout?

Comment: where you r using this, can you tell the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sat's answer is correct, i.e., you need a proper layout, but `setContentView()` **is not the only way to reference a View**. You can use a [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate a parent layout of the `View` (even if it is not shown) and use that newly inflated layout to reference the View.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  Context context;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
// the rest of yout code

private void someCallback() {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
     (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.iconLayout, null);
  ImageView img = (ImageView) ll.findViewById(R.id.application_icon);
// you can do whatever you need with the img (get the Bitmap, maybe?)
```

The only change you need to your xml file is to add an ID to the parent layout, so you can use it with the `LayoutInflater`:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="iconLayout"
<!-- all the rest of your layout -->
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/application_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- all the rest of your layout -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, I learned a different lesson. I was using a LayoutInflater within an ArrayAdapter class. The problem is that I had accidentally linked to the wrong xml layout when i called inflate().  The layout I linked to just happened to have a TextView and CheckBox with identical ids but no ImageView. My other two view items linked just fine, which threw me off when the ImageView did not. I think what I'm going to take away from this is that generic ids are maybe not the best idea and something more descriptive like "application_list_check" might have been better than "check" and saved me some time.

Answer (score 1):

When you are referencing the imageView , make sure that you are using the proper layout, i.e. setContentView(R.layout.yourIntendedXmlLayout);

That xml should contain your imageView. Then you can refer to your imageView.

Answer (score 0):

use

`ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.application_icon)`;